# Does deploy of a pre-compiled IIS site show faster first load times?

Tags: asp.net, iis

Using the [asp.net compiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) I have compiled a site with aspx pages. The contents of the pages have been replaced with placeholder text and the bin folder now contains multiple App_Web_*dll files. There are also multiple *.ascx.hash.compiled files.

I've copied this folder to the webserver and deployed by creating a Virtual Directory that points to this folder. The site works but I am not seeing any improvement in first load times.

When the first aspx is requested, the IIS asp.net cache is rebuilt in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files. This is as time consuming as dynamic compilation of source files. It almost seems like the site is being recompiled. The layout of the IIS asp.net cache is different from the site folder. There are App_Web_*dll files in the cache folder but different names compared to the site.

Am I missing some configuration to get this working right?

Comment: Pre-compilation doesn't really help first-load times except in cases where a site has hundreds of .aspx/.ascx files. Also if you're on a shared host then it's probably under a lot of load too and while there would be an improvement, it wouldn't be as-significant. Have you taken detailed measurements?

Comment: I misinterpreted the article at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860%28v=vs.90%29.aspx. Faster response times are seen only for large sites. I have a smaller site of under 200 pages and am not seeing any improvement in load times.

Comment: @Dai I've edited the question to be explicit about the load times. Do you want to paste your commend as a reply?

Comment: If you using iis 8.0 and have access to settings, you can set Auto-Start to true and Start mode "Always Running" for application pool